# Компьютер с первого раза не включается, ОС Linux в чем может быть проблема?

Tags: linux

ОС Kali Linux.
До Kali было windows 10. До windows 10 был Linux. Я думаю в этом проблем нет, я ничего не трогал, нигде не копался но не включается с первого раза, было ли у кого то после установки Kali Linux ?

Comment: Что конкретно означает «не включается с первого раза»? Что происходит в первый раз?

Comment: Комп выключен, нажимаю кнопку для включения кнопка сгорается, но монитор черный ничего не происходит, ждал 5 минут монитор все же черный... потом перезагружаю снова так, ну кароче картина появляется через нескольо перезагрузок, и такое уже с того момента как установил Linux после Windows, ну иногда да с первого раза все норм, кстати еще один момент, когда с первого раза не включается кнопка перезагрузки горит красным

Comment: @chc судя по описанию, линукс ни при чем. Похоже "высохли" конденсаторы на материнской плате. Теряют ёмкость. Спустя какоето время, пока вы перезагружаете, конденсаторы нагреваются и их емкость увеличивается до возможности запустить компьютер. На следующем "холодном" старте повторится то же самое. Вам надо везти комп в сервис-центр, чтобы проверили и возможно перепаяли

Comment: А почему так происходит ? Как они это могут терять емкость ? Комп всегда был пуст тоесть некогда не нагревался не когда в игры не играл, только что то читал или изучал программирования, не когда не пользовался с gui редакторами, только vim... как так ?

Comment: комп абсолютно пуст... В домашней директории есть только одна папка Project там всего 2 папки, в одной изучаю c/c++ а в другой python и все ...

Comment: да и всегда был пуст...

Comment: это случается по многим причинам. От времени. От нахождения рядом с батареей. От дешевых запчастей. Опять же не факт, что именно в конденсаторах дело. Просто похоже. Может у блока питания мощность падает. Лучше продиагностировать у профессионалов

Comment: понято спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Блок питания или цепь питания не выдают мощность требуемую для старта процессора.

Замена блока питания поможет с вероятностью 90%